# How can I fit a popup onto the users screen without going over Windows' Taskbar?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've been trying to make my popup check the user's screen size and then fit itself onto the screen, it works on all browsers, except IE9 or lower, I'd like to make it work at least on IE8 up. May someone provide me an explanation of how this can be done.

***My code:*** ( You should try this code on your desktop, the problem seems to happen on IE 9 and below, but not on the emulator's IE9 )

```js
var ie = (function(){
  var undef,
      v = 3,
      div = document.createElement('div'),
      all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');
  while (
    div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
    all[0]
  );
  return v > 4 ? v : undef;
}());
if(ie < 9){
  alert("My sincere apologies, but your IE version is not supported!\nUninstall it or go f*ck yourself!");
}
function fe()
{
  window.open('http://www.google.com.br','janela','menubar=yes,screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0,location=no,status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes,width=' + (screen.width - 15) + ',height=' + (screen.availHeight - 65));
}
function fc(url)
{
  var winFeatures = 'screenX=0,screenY=0,top=0,left=0,scrollbars,width=100,height=100';
  var winName = 'window';
  var win = window.open(url,winName, winFeatures); 
  var extraWidth = win.screen.availWidth - win.outerWidth;
  var extraHeight = win.screen.availHeight - win.outerHeight;
  win.resizeBy(extraWidth, extraHeight);      
  return win;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>winds</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="Javascript:if(ie < 10){fe();}else{fc('');}">Popup</a>

  </body>
</html>
```